# How to get UIWebView working

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, webview, outlet

(Link to errors here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkrcD.jpg)

I'm starting to work on iOS development, and I'm relatively new.

I was looking for tutorials on how to display web content in the app, and so I used the `UIWebView`.

In the tutorial I found I followed the steps exactly, but when I went to do the last step (linking the outlet) I got an error.

The two files I edited are `DataViewController.h` and `DataViewController.m`

This is the tutorial I followed: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NFffF9tRbak

I'm using `XCode 4.6`

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I will once they solve my issue :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renaming may still cause some erors, there is a chance, so its better to set the connections again.its quite simple.
You can solve this by following these steps:

1.

[image]

Click on the cross sign left to Web View , that will remove the invalid outlet.

2.then, connect the existing `@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *myWebView` by control dragging the '+' sign left to the property outlet to your webview in the Interface Builder.

This will solve your problem, happens just because you are new to xcode. Will get better as soon as you get familiar.

EDIT:If its still not clear, see the screen shots below;

your outlet in yourviewcontroller.h may be like this now,
[image]

and in your xib,

[image]
it may look like this.

So what you should do is, just control drag the while blank circle left to @property outlet (first image) to the webview in your xib (highlightened one in second image). It will connect itself.

hope its clear now

Regards

Comment: When I press the x to remove the invalid outlet the whole webView outlet goes away, so I can't just relink (like this: http://puu.sh/283vo)

Comment: let it go, you dont need it, you are trying to connect again.

Comment: I also tried dragging it to the "Web View" bar on the side, same thing.

Comment: Would it help if I shared my screen? Or sent the xcode project?

Comment: Yes I sent it, you can delete your email

Answer (score 0):

Change your outlet name from `webView` to `myWebView` in outlets

Edit:
or change your UIWebView object name from `myWebView` to `webView` in your code

Comment: check the edit to my answer, that should be more clear for you to understand and easier for me to explain :)